# Hardware scan code to ascii char conversion

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard, ascii

Is there a Windows API to translate a hardware scan code to an ASCII character?

Comment: Are you trying to get what the keyboard character equivalent is? If so there is an API for converting to virtual key codes [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: To follow up on the above comment, you'll want to use `MapVirtualKeyEx` if you want to convert a *scancode* instead of a virtual key code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MapVirtualKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ToAsciiEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you are looking for - sample usage [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/directx-and-xna/converting-scan-codes-to-ascii-r842)

Comment: That code will not work on keyboards with dead keys or IME. Conversion to characters for those keyboards is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is a Unicode operating system, it doesn't particularly fancy ASCII.  Nor does it have a bias towards the way people across the world use their machines.

The mapping from a *virtual key* produced by a keyboard input event like WM_KEYDOWN is performed by the window procedure.  Which produces a WM_CHAR key message, the underlying api function is ToUnicodeEx(), exposed to you as well.  A function with a lot of arguments, the lpKeyState argument is essential to translate modifier and dead keys, like Alt+Gr and Shift.  The dwhkl argument is essential to allow different users use different keyboad layouts.  You do not want to get in the business of making the same translation, particularly the keyboard state is a process-local property.

But ToUnicodeEx() is what it takes.